# I am officially missing something about transient posts

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination, query, transient

I have no issue creating transients. What I have an issue with is pagination - and I have made posts on it before and every one sates that the query must look like, for example:

```
        $queried_post = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' )
        );
```

Which is then:

```
$query = new WP_Query($queried_post);
```

and stored:

```
set_transient('posts', $query, 60); // For testing purposes, we reset every 60 seconds.
```

So then I do:

```
    gloabl $wp_query;

    $original = $wp_query;
    // Obviously you would do checks to see if the transient
    // exists. But lets assume it always exists.
    $wp_query = get_transient('posts');

    if($wp_query->have_posts()){
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
            $wp_query->the_post();
            // display content ... 
        }

        var_dump($wp_query->max_num_pages); // Shows me: float 4
        echo get_next_posts_link( __( 'Next', 'textdomain'), $wp_query->max_num_pages );
        echo get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Previous', 'textdomain'), $wp_query->max_num_pages );
    }

    $wp_query = $original;
```

I have even attempted everything I know, including testing the original query and the pagination on that works just fine, I can paginated back to 4 pages and forward to the latest. So the query **not set in a transient** works. But setting it up in a transient causes pagination to fail...

Why? I cant figure out. Can some one tell me?

Comment: what is `$posts_inside`? I don't see that defined anywhere.

Comment: also, you're only putting one page of posts in the transient, for any other page your transient always contains the first page of posts (or whatever page you originally put in the transient).

Comment: @Milo Your second answer makes no sense please create an example if you can. Your first answer - I knew I made a mistake some where, so I checked it out and fixed it in the OP and its still not paginating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have 10 pages of posts, 10 posts per page. When you load the first page and the transient doesn't yet exist, your query loads the first page (10 posts) and you put that in a transient.

Now you navigate to page 2, and check if the transient exists. it does (you set it on page 1), so you load that instead of running a new query. Except your transient still contains posts 1-10, not 11-20 which you're supposed to see on page 2.

You need to set a unique transient key for each page of posts, something like:

```
set_transient( 'posts_' . get_query_var( 'paged' ) , $query, 60);
```

and then fetch them by page:

```
get_transient( 'posts_' . get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
```

Comment: is this documented in the codex some where? I have never seen this before.